# How to add a word at the first of every lines?

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk

File1:

```
Data will be inserted on Thursday  
Messages has been sent at 6pm  
Office hours is from 9am to 6pm  
All the employees are present
```

Output what I want:

```
DMS Data will be inserted on Thursday  
DMS Messages has been sent at 6pm  
DMS Office hours is from 9am to 6pm  
DMS All the employees are present
```

-or-

Output what I want:

```
Data will be inserted on Thursday DMS
Messages has been sent at 6pm DMS
Office hours is from 9am to 6pm DMS
All the employees are present DMS
```

I want to add the word *DMS* in every lines of my file. **It may be added at the first or at the end of the line.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, it will help you. Open the file in `vi` editor:

```
$ vi /file/location  

:1,100 s/^/DMS/ --> Enter
```

- `1,100` is exactly from which line you want to start and end.
- `s` is the substitution command and `^` means the the line starting.

Or you can do it without opening the file, using GNU sed:

```
sed -i 's/^/DMS /' /your/file/location
```

Comment: I don't think you *can* do it without opening the file - at least not without directly editing the underlying block device, and probably the filesystem will object to that, anyway - and I'm pretty positive you definitely can't w/ `sed`by asking it to open the file.

Comment: I was not able to modify my question as I was facing some technical problem. The question has been marked as duplicate. But today I have again edited my question. But if I want to add the word at the last of my line, then what could be the solution. @cuonglm Your solution has helped me.

Comment: @Nainita: You should raise a new question.